# Photon energy dissipation

Tags: photons

Okay, we need a "perfect" match, (epsilon identically zero?).  I could not find anything indicating whether the levels can change with say heat and how the heat manifests itself inside an atom, in particular, the classical notion is that the heat that is manifested in vibrating atoms and molecules.  What is the mechanism by which heat gets inside the atom to perhaps change the shell energies.

One answer said that incident photons with greater energy are partially absorbed and move on at lower energy (what happens to them if they have less energy than the inner shell?  Seems like they will go on forever), yet another answer says the match must be exact.  Any additional input to reconcile or expand would be great.  Not time critical for today.

Answer (score 0):

'Heat' as in vibrations, only makes sense if you are talking about a system of atoms, and it will be related with the energy of vibrations of that system. If your system has only a few number of atoms, you might be able to see that it vibrates only at discrete frequencies or modes (phonons), that have a particular energy. As you increase the number of atoms and your system gets larger, the number of modes will also increase to a point that it might seem that they are continuous...and you get the macroscopic behavior of a material.

Comment: Then am I correct in inferring that the new atoms added would have slightly different energy levels than the initial small group of atoms, even though they are of the same element and at the same average temperature (averaged over all atoms of that element in the set.  From this, I would conclude that there is a joint probaility density for vectors consisting of the shell energies with average and covariance matrix perhaps related to temperature?  If this interpretation is correct then it would be a nice step forward for me.

Comment: Adding new atoms (same kind of atom) at 0 Kelvin (aka, no vibration) will not modify the energy density of the material, it will only open up the possibility of new modes of vibrations when you add heat, these modes will increase in energy as you add atoms, but that does not mean that they are always active, you must provide the energy to activate them. Or in other words, phonons are Bosons.